# Where would I find information on programmatically modifying the Windows 7 start menu?

Tags: windows-7

Where would I find information on programmatically modifying the Windows 7 start menu? We have a large number of network programs that are made difficult to access using the new Windows 7 menu, ideally we want an expanding menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this via group policy assuming all the machines are on a domain. Although, for the specifics you may want to ask over on serverfault :-)